# why won't my simple turning argument that won't respond for some reason? (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, sprite, rigid-bodies

I have a 2d sprite that I'm just trying to get to flip on its x axis on the press of a button. For some reason it just isn't responding to me even though all the other arguments are. I'm not receiving any error messages. Does anyone have a solution? It's driving me crazy because I've done this a bazillion times with enemies and now all of a sudden nothing is happening. The arguments are in the Flip and Flipper functions but I left the rest in there jic you see another argument that may be preventing the flip from happening.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dragoonDetection : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
[HideInInspector]
public bool flight;
[HideInInspector]
public regDragon detector;
public float flightHeight;
public float flightDistance;
private bool facingRight = true;
private bool state1;
public float changeTimer = 0f;
public float changeDelay = 0.5f;
public float attackTimer = 0;
public float attackDelay = 1f;
public float speed = 1f;
public Transform Player; 


void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update()

{
    Detected ();
    ChangeTimes (); 
    StateChanger ();  
    Flip ();
}


void Flipper()
{
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
}

void Flip()
{

    if (facingRight && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        Flipper ();
        Debug.Log ("left");
    }

    if (!facingRight && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        Flipper ();
        Debug.Log ("right");
    }

}

void Detected()
{
    if (detector == null) {
        return;
    } else 

    {
        if (detector.detected) {
            flight = true;
            anim.SetTrigger ("flight");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, flightHeight);
            changeDelay -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}

void ChangeTimes ()
{
    if (changeDelay <= 0 && flight) {
        state1 = true;
    }
}

void StateChanger ()
{
    if (state1) {

        flightHeight = 0f;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == ("arrow")) {
        flight = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("flight");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with your code. Can you confirm if the x value of the transform changes on key press and that this script is attached to the gameobject that has the sprite, or a parent gameobject.

Comment: Can you confirm, using the debugger, whether or not you get past the if-statement and into the `Flipper` method?

Comment: all of that is a yes. the parent gameobject is the one with the sprite, animator, rigidbody2d and script. And I had a debug.log occur whenever Flipper is called and that came up as well.

Comment: i even commented out the other functions in the Update() to see if those were interfering. No difference with the flip not responding.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the `Flip` property of the `SpriteRenderer`?  According to the Unity docs:  `While Sprites can be flipped by setting negative transform.scale, this has the side effect of also flipping the child GameObjects and also flipping the colliders, which can be performance intensive or otherwise not preferred.

The SpriteRenderer flipping feature provides a lightweight alternative which doesn’t affect any other components or GameObjects. It simply flips the rendered sprite on x or y axis and nothing else.`

Comment: Apparently the `Flip` property is only available in Unity 2017 and higher so it might not apply to your situation.

Comment: well, i did have it that way before. It was originally typed,        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);, and vice versa. But it has the same results. I know that the flip method does work for my main character script cuz that's still in there. The alternative mentioned is what my enemies use and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Something was wrong with animation itself. IDK how it happened because that was all fine too. There were no extra parameters or specific locations where the animation took place. But I reinserted the sprites and now it works fine. My Unity has been doing random act-ups lately, where things that were working fine forever suddenly started rebelling for no reason (I had 5 for a while now). But its okay. Thanks everyone for throwing in your two cents.